# creating custom action for controller yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to yii.

I've created a controller called CatalogController. I want to create a custom action called actionClear(). I've followed steps from documentation and searching on-line but when I navigate to catalog/clear, it redirects back to homepage of site. I don't know what other steps I should be taking.

I've done the following so far:

in CatalogController:

```
public function actionClear() {
     $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Catalog');
     $this->render('clear',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
}
```

overridden rules() method in controller:

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'clear'=>'application.controllers.post.ClearAction',
    );
}
```

a new custom action under protected/controllers/post

```
class ClearAction extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'fart';die;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the url `index.php?r=catalog/clear` or jus `index.php/catalog/clear` ?

By default in yii only the first one will work. For the second one you need to activate it in the url manager:

In your config file edit the url manager as follow:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Source: [The Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls)